# Should I test view's attributes in unit tests?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, selenium

I am wondering what is a proper way to unit test a Django view, for example this one:

```
class UserListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    model = get_user_model()
    template_name = 'users/user_list.html'
    ordering = 'last_name'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.queryset = self.model.objects.all().annotate(
            full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')
        )
        return super().get_queryset()
```

I'm currently unit testing the `get_queryset` method. This gives me 100% coverage of this view, but should I also test, for example, default ordering in a **unit test**? Or should this be tested in an integration/system test only (e.g. using Selenium or Django's Client)?

On one side, the `ordering` attribute is part of the view and it influences it's behaviour, on the other side, it's used by a third party code only.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, yes, you should add a test for that.  On the one hand, you can bet that Django has a test already to make sure this attribute works as advertised (Django has really good test coverage).

However, my reasoning goes like this: suppose the upstream `ListView` decided to change the name of that attribute to something else.  They renamed it to `list_ordering`, say.

Fast forward 7 months later, you bump the version number of Django to try out some shiny new feature.  Writing the `UserListView` is now a distant memory.  As a developer, you want to know that the default ordering you asked for has stopped working in the newer version of Django, and a failed test here would show you that - it draws attention to some area of your code that needs updating now.

Of course we should read the release notes carefully when upgrading 3rd party libraries, but it's even better to have tests that talk to you directly!

Comment: I will definitely test it, but my question was if this should be tested in a **unit test** or in an integration/system test. Because this attribute is only some kind of "preset" for a third-party code, so I am not sure it is suitable to be tested in a unit test, which should use as little dependencies as possible.

Comment: That's up to you.  If you have a separate integration test suite, it would probably be better to check the list ordering behaviour there, since this is something that can probably only break by a change in the 3rd party code.  Unit testing that the attribute exists on the `UserListView` class would be pretty pointless, since it would miss the most obvious failure mode.

Comment: I have a separate Selenium test suite, so I can test it there. So if I understand it right, I don't need to unit test class attributes unless they contain some kind of logic (for example list comprehension), right?